# Response from WebServiceCallout is null when using WebServiceMock

Tags: unit-test, webservices

I try to write unit test for a code that invokes a web service.
Apart from the test I created implementation of WebServiceMock as to guideline:

```
@isTest
global class WebServiceMockImpl implements WebServiceMock {
   global void doInvoke(
           Object stub,
           Object request,
           Map<String, Object> response,
           String endpoint,
           String soapAction,
           String requestName,
           String responseNS,
           String responseName,
           String responseType) {
    //construct response_x
    ...
    response.put('response_x', response_x); 
}
```

The webservice callout is invoked with generated from WSDL code as below (parameters are not exact):

```
    WebServiceCallout.invoke(
      this,
      request_x,
      response_map_x,
      new String[]{endpoint_x,
      'http://...',
      'http://...',
      'MethodName',
      'http://...',
      'MethodNameResponse',
      'ProxyClass.MethodNameResponse_element'}
    );
    response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
```

The issue is that response_x == null, while I put response_x is not null in WebServiceMockImpl.doInvoke method.

Comment: Can you add the more of the test script?

Comment: Yes it would be good to see how your initialising response_x in your mock class. If its conditional (because your handling multiple request/responses) then maybe some issue in that logic results in the wrong type or null response_x. Have you tried an System.assert on the response_x not being null and also the correct type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I had a silly mistake. Somehow I assumed that response will be null in doInvoke and I had to create it like this

```
response = new Map<String, SpecificClassName>();
```

When I removed that, the issue was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how response_x is supposed to work *after* the call in a mock scenario. However, everything works exactly as expected for me - it's just that the result I'm evaluating is the actual result that I expected from the web service - not response_x.

So for example, after preparing my mock (just like you've done, assuming response_x is properly constructed) I just make the callout and get the actual value, like this:

```
static testMethod void testGetValue() 
{
    System.Test.startTest();
    System.Test.setMock(WebServiceMock.class, new GetValueMock());

    wwwSomeSiteCom.SomeWebServicePort p = new wwwSomeSiteCom.SomeWebServicePort();
    wwwSomeSiteCom.valueResult valueResult = p.getValue(''); // Just returns an Integer (set to 93)
    system.assert(valueResult.theValue == 93); // <---- OK
    System.Test.stopTest();
}
```